# Validation and Verification

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What is the difference between Validation and Verification?

> An event pass must be verified.
>
> An event pass must be validated.

Comment: " 'An' event pass"...

Answer (score 2):

> Verify

It means to prove that something exists or is true, or to make certain that something is correct.

[Source: Verify](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/verify)

> Validate

It means to make something officially acceptable or approved, especially after examining it.

[Source: Validate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/validate)

Both of the given sentences are both technically and grammatically correct. However, taking your context under consideration, I'd suggest you to use "validate".

Comment: Take a scenario I am going to an event with someone else pass, does only validation of my pass will prevent me from attending event or it will allow me to attend the event ?

Comment: @JiteshNK: Apologies for putting wrong definition earlier. Now, as the definition says, to validate is **to make something officially acceptable**. And yes, It'll prevent you from entering the event as it's officially not acceptable for you to take someone else's pass and attend the event.

Comment: @7R3X Validation will never check whether I am holding someone else pass. Validation will only check whether I am holding legitimate pass or not. Verification will check the valid pass that I am holding has my name written on it or not.

Comment: A pass would be **officially acceptable or approved** only after it has been authenticated for correct date, event and the holder.

Comment: @7R3X Verification needs some external proof to confirm the process. I think verification can only be done after validating

Comment: What exactly was your purpose behind putting this question? I've posted an answer with sources that I'd trust more than I'd trust you. They clearly differentiate the usage of both the words. Not only that but I've written it again after your comment to clarify it further. If you think you can get me to trust you instead of these sources, you're most welcome to try.

Comment: I was asking what is the difference between validation and verification, and for both the sentences. Don't get over I am not trying to prove you wrong here. Answer you had given, that I had already searched.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in meaning is subtle but they do describe different actions. The difference does depend on context. In your particular examples:

Verifying an event pass would involve checking that it was not a forgery.

Validating an event pass would often involve adding a stamp or mark to show the holder had passed through security with a verified pass.

Comment: Tompsett, this is what I understand is when you are talking for validation, that means you are checking its legitimate or not. And if you are talking verification, that means they are correct or not.
Considering my example both sentence have there own set of meaning.